# Sitemap is showing Html Error

Tags: html, xml, .htaccess, web

I generated sitemap for my website, then i uploaded into google webmasters, Everytime google webmasters is showing following below messagee, please help me to sort it out

Google Webmasters Message

Sitemap is HTML
Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading `HTML` and Google Webmasters don't support that format. The common format is `XML`

From link:

> If you have many sitemaps, you can use a sitemaps index file as a way
>   to submit them at once. The XML format of a sitemap index file is very
>   similar to the XML format of a sitemap file. The sitemap index file
>   uses the following XML tags:
>
> ```
> sitemapindex - the parent tag surrounds the file.
> sitemap - the parent tag for each sitemap listed in the file (a child of sitemapindex)
> loc - the location of the sitemap (a child of sitemap)
> lastmod - the last modified date of the sitemap (optional)
> ```
>
> You can see the Sitemap Protocol page for more information on syntax.
>
> The following example shows a sitemap index in XML format that lists
>   two sitemaps:

More information read here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en